# Programmatic link to directly open Office Documents

Tags: spservices

When a view that has links to Office documents is added to a webpart the click event opens the document directly. But when the link is built using CAML and SP the click evokes the "Do you want to open the requested document." message

Is there some sharepoint magic dust that can be added to the programmatic construction of the link so that it opens the Office document similar to the view that is attached to the webpart?

Thanks

Comment: I use this  anchor element:
<a class="ms-listlink ms-draggable" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this,event,'0','SharePoint.OpenDocuments','')" onclick="return DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3','0','SharePoint.OpenDocuments','','','','115','0','0','0x7fffffffffffffff')" href="[file path]" DragId="93">[file_name]</a>

extracted directly from the library
greetings

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it need the `?Web=1.` have added to the link